# RealityKit and Reality Composer incompatibile with iOS 12 support

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

In a new update of my app I want to integrate a new AR function using the Reality Composer, this function will available only for iOS 13, but I have a problem.
I want to maintain my project compatible with iOS 12, but I'm unable to do this.
When I set the compatibility with iOS 12 the swift file auto-generated by the .rcproject give me a lots of errors "... is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer". I tried to add "@available(iOS 13.0, *)" but when I rebuild the project xCode restores the original file and returns me the same errors "... is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer".

There is a solution for these?

[image: 3]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> `RealityKit` features are directly implemented in **iOS/iPadOS 13** and higher, so the only way to work with [RealityKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit) framework is to use it in apps with targets of iOS 13/14/15. OS versions lower than mentioned don't support RealityKit in any way.